# Tengo un problema con mi formulario en laravel

Tags: laravel, login, mensajes

No se muestra los errores en de login intento generar una login fallido a proposito y no me da el error que quiero, no se muestra el mensaje de error que quiero generar con la variable $error

no encuentro la falla mira el contralador pero no se donde se genera el error para que no se muestren los mensaje

```
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
    <div class="login-logo">
        <a href="{{route('inicio')}}">Biblioteca </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-logo -->
    <div class="login-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Inicio su session</p>
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <div class="alert-text">
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <span>{{ $error }}</span>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
        @if($errors->any()) {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }} @endif 
        <form action="{{route('login_post')}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" value="{{old('usuario')}}" placeholder="Usuario">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="{{old('password')}}" placeholder="Contraseña">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Login</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], considera editar y agregar tu código, al momento tu pregunta es muy amplia y poco clara para responder

Comment: use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public  function index(){

        return view('seguridad.index');
    }

Comment: public function username()
    {
        return 'usuario';
    }